# What is the genus of $T^3$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

The Wikipedia page on genus for 3-manifolds is pretty weak. They really only use the intuitive definition of "number of handles" for a 2-manifold. Just as you can get $S^2$ from $T^2$ by "eliminating the hole," I want to see how you can get $S^3$ from $T^3$ by "eliminating the hole."

Comment: There is an invariant dubbed tri-genus which allow decomposition into orientable handle bodies: If the 3-manifold is orientable one needs two (Heegaard) and if the 3-manifold is non-orientable you will need three orientable handle bodies.

Comment: Genus of a closed connected oriented 3-manifold $M$ is defined as the minimal genus of the surface in the Heegaard decomposition of $M$. For $T^3$ the genus is 3, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegaard_splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Genus is only really defined for a 2-Manifold. The wikipedia article you are looking at extends this definition to a small class of 3 manifolds called handlebodies. These are "filled in" 2-manifolds and so we define their genus to be the genus of their boundary. The "handles" are not merely intuitive crutches, but in fact is the number of 1-handles of a [Handle Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition). The closest thing to a genus of a 3 manifold is probably the smallest genus of a [Heegaard Splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegaard_splitting).

Comment: How would you distinguish between $T^3$ and $S^3$? To distinguish between $T^2$ and $S^2$, we just say that $T^2$ is genus 1 while $S^2$ is genus 0. They are both compact, bounded surfaces.

Comment: There are various ways to tell higher dimensional manifolds apart. The most useful one you will encounter is called the fundamental group which is a way to associate a group to a manifold based on how loops on the manifold behave. Just as in the case for $S^2$, every loop on $S^3$ can be shrunk to a point. Convince yourself that this can not be done on $T^2$ which will distinguish $T^2$ and $S^2$. Using some nice properties of the fundamental group you can figure out that the fundamental group of $T^3$ is $\mathbb{Z}^3$ distinguishing it from $S^3$ whose fundamental group is trivial.